# Не корректно работает { link } в React Router. Почему не переходит по локальной ссылки?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Столкнулся с необычной проблемой в React Router, я прописал локальным ссылкам {link} и указал куда  динамически при клике должна переходить ссылка(на другую страницу), в адресной строке url меняется корректно, но без принудительной перезагрузки страница не меняется. То есть, при клике url меняется правильно, но нужно обновить страницу, что бы перейти по ссылки. Ошибок в консоли нет.

*App.js*

```
import Header from "./components/Header/Header"
import Articles from "./components/Articles/Articles.jsx"

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router, Switch as
    Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom"

import About from "./padge/About"



function App() {
  return (
    <div>

      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>

          <Route exact path="/">

            <Articles />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/About" element={<About />}>
            <About />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}



  Header.jsx
введите сюда код
```

*About.jsx*

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
export const About = () => {
  return (

    <div style={{ padding: '20px' }}>

      About compani
      <Link to="/">Back to Home</Link>
    </div>
  )

}

export default About
```

*header.jsx*

```
import React from 'react'
import LogoImg from '../../assets/img/Logo.svg'
import { menu } from './menu'

import styles from './Header.module.scss'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.header}>
      <div className={styles.logo}>
        <img src={LogoImg} alt="logo" className={styles['logo__img']} />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
          
          <ul className={styles.menu}>
            {menu.map((item, index) =>(
            <li key={`menu item ${index}`}>
              <Link to={item.link}>{item.title}</Link>
              </li>
              ))}</ul>

          <div className={styles.buttons}>
            <button className={styles['login-up']}>Login</button>
            <button className={styles['sing-up']}>Sing up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Новый реакт не работает со старой версией (в моём случае была версия 5.3.0) роутера. Помогла установка последней версии роутера